# Trying to change scroll bar width in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I have found numerous suggestions on how to do this by editing the gtk.css file in the Theme folders. However, when I try to edit the files, they are read-only and appear to be in a read-only disk. For an example of some paths:

```
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0
```

Am I looking in the wrong spot or is there something special I have to do the edit these files? I have tried using `sudo gedit` but get the same error.

Comment: "Ubuntu 20.14"? There is no such version. Do you mean Ubuntu 20.10 or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: Sorry should be 20.04

Comment: I don't know about the `snap` location. But regarding themes in `/usr/share/themes/`, I would suggest that you create a directory at `/home/<YOURUSERNAME>/.themes/` and copy the original from `/usr/share/themes/` there, and modify only your copy. You will need the `gnome-tweaks` app to enable such themes living in your home folder.

Answer (score 5):

You have to be root in order to edit files in these folders. In a two-step process, first open a standard terminal window and type:

```
sudo gnome-terminal
```

which will open a second terminal window as root. Then, typing:

```
gedit [filename]
```

will allow edits to the files.

More on the changes needed to increase scrollbar width. First

```
cd /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0
```

in the root terminal. then type

```
gedit gtk.css
```

which allow you to edit the gtk.css file. add the following to the file:

> scrollbar slider {
> /* Size of the slider */
> min-width: 20px;
> min-height: 20px;
> border-radius: 22px;
>
> ```
> /* Padding around the slider */
> border: 5px solid transparent; }
> ```

save and close. Do the same to a file named gtk-dark.css. Move to

```
cd /usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-3.20
```

and edit the same files in that folder. Reboot and you scrollbars will be 20px wide.

Comment: The formatting of the code snippet did not turn out right. Should be:   
scrollbar slider {
    /* Size of the slider */
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 22px;

    /* Padding around the slider */
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}

Comment: fixed formatting

Comment: There is no need to save this as root. You can change only for your user saving it as `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

Comment: note that this need to be added to correct theme (the one that is in use based on UI that is in use) there are  Yaru, Yaru-dark, Yaru-Light themes and then there are gtk versions 2.0, 3.0 and 3.20 in case someone need to add these to later versions of the os