# Enhance contrast of Ubuntu Gnome3 scrollbar

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, scrollbar

I view PDFs a lot and I need to quickly navigate them.

Of course, I am using the scrollbar, but in Ubuntu 20.04 gnome3 the scrollbar handle (the item that you grab with a left click and then move the mouse up down, just to be extremely clear ) is REALLY hard to see.

I attach an image (where I have drawn a blue arrow to show the scroll cursor) and as you see it is very hard to see/distinguish from the background.

Is there anything to enhance its contrast? like filling it in blue color, while keeping the background scroll area grey?

I searched askubuntu, found similar question, but none of them solved my problem.

Some answer mentions installing a package "gnome colour chooser"  but in fact, this is obsolete and no more available (at least on Ubuntu 20.04).
In the answers I found searching, someone mentions gnome themes, (not regardiing the scrollbar though) but I am no expert sadly, and I would like to ask the community for help.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: There is a "High contrast" setting in "Settings - Accessibility", but that changes all UI elements and may or may not be too much. It is worthwhile trying it. Otherwise you will depend on finding a different theme, or perhaps someone can suggest a hack to the css code of the current theme.

Comment: you should be able to modify the CSS in the files listed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299065/trying-to-change-scroll-bar-width-in-ubuntu-20-04), but probably it's better to copy the files to your home directory and use gnome-tweaks to use themes in your home directory. I don't have access to an Ubuntu machine right now to try it out and give exact directions, but if you copy files to your home directory and mess with them you can't really break anything